# Find the limit of a Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring, area, riemann-sum

The function is $f(x) = 1-x^2$. I'm stuck as I can't factor the expression in the last line to find the limit.
[image: I just want to find the limit of A sub 1]

Comment: $ f (X)=(1-X)(1+X) $.

Answer (score 1):

The expression from your last line can be simplified:
\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{n} \bigg[n-\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg(\frac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}{6}\bigg)\bigg] 
&  = \bigg[\frac{n}{n}-\frac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\bigg] \\[0.1in]
& = 1-\frac{1}{6} \bigg( \frac{n+2}{n} \bigg)\bigg(\frac{2n+1}{n}\bigg) \\[0.1in]
& = 1-\frac{1}{6} \bigg( 1+\frac{2}{n} \bigg)\bigg( 2+\frac{1}{n} \bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: I see how you got your first line but when I tried to simplify it I ended up with (4n^3/6n^3) - 3n^2 - n.

Comment: Something is wrong, because the coefficient for $n^3$ should not be $4$. If you expand $n(n+2)(2n+1)$, the first term will be $n \cdot n \cdot 2n = 2n^3$. In any case, you don't really need to expand, as shown in my suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

The last step should then be
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\{1-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\{1-\frac{2n^3+\cdots}{6n^3}\}=1-\frac26$$

Comment: why didn't you include the remaining n terms?

Comment: In this case(division of two polynomial of the same degree say $s$) the limit is the division of the coefficients of the $n^s$